# Does the sum over the normed differential of the prime power function equal $2\log2\pi$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p\in \Bbb P$ a prime and a prime power function:

$$\xi_p(x) = p^x$$

with $x \in \Bbb R^+_0$

hence:

$$\xi'_p = \frac{d}{dx}\xi_p=\xi_p \log p$$

Taking into account  [E. Muñoz García and R. Pérez Marco](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00220-007-0350-z) we conclude:

$$\sum_p^\infty\frac{\xi'_p}{\xi_p}=2\log2\pi$$

Is the above statement/theorem mathematically correct?

Comment: I think there is a typo since the given sum is the same as the sum over the logarithms of the primes. I think you mean the reciprocals of those logarithms.